# VirtualHost Forbidden

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.2, virtualhost, osx-snow-leopard

Hey guys, I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard with the default Apache 2 installation that it comes with and PHP 5 enabled.

Anyways, I have configured a VirtualHost whose `DocumentRoot` is under `/Users/blaenk/Sites`. This works perfectly fine, but if I set it to a directory within my `code` directory, `Users/blaenk/code/php/somesite`, it gives me the **Forbidden** error. Apparently this has to do with permissions on the folders, as they are different:

```
drwxr-xr-x+  6 blaenk  staff   204B Dec 20 16:09 Sites/
drwx------  15 blaenk  staff   510B Nov 28 18:35 code/
```

I tried making the `code`, `php`, and `somesite` directories all 755, but that did not seem to solve the issue. I also did `chmod -R 755 ~/code/php/blaenkdenum` , to no avail.

I would appreciate any help which you guys can provide. Let me know if I'm missing any information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your error log for details of exactly *why* access was forbidden; it can be because of filesystem permissions, but it can also be because of Apache path permissions -- if the Apache config has something like:

```
<Directory /Users/*/Sites>
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

But nothing equivalent for `/Users/*/code`, then Apache won't allow HTTP access to your vhost location, regardless of what the filesystem permissions might be.

Comment: It says [Sun Dec 20 16:30:07 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/blaenk/code/php/blaenkdenum/, so I'm guessing it is indeed a configuration issue. I went ahead and added a Directory block to allow traffic to that path and it fixed the issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the permissions on the files you are trying to serve are 755 as well, not just the directory.

Comment: Yep, I did chmod -R 755 ~/code/php/blaenkdenum, restarted apache, still Forbidden.

Comment: Glad to see you got it worked out:)